# kupdated slows down voice transmission

Tags: c, linux, audio

I'm working on a device which primarily serves as a VoIP terminal. Currently I wrote an application whose main purpose is to record sound from the enlightened sound daemon v0.2.38 ( and to do some magic with it ).

The problem is, that writing of the recorded data to disk ( or even calling rename to move a file ) causes kupdated daemon to eat much of the cpu speed and the quality of the voice transmission to drop drastically for a short period.

I've tried different things to speed things up ( setting priorities etc. ) but it always ends up in kupdated using 50% of the cpu when flushing its buffers.

Can you think of any way ( maybe some kernel module? ) that will make esd have greater priority then kupdated when writing to files?

Some data on the system: linux kernel 2.4.29, gcc v2.91.66.

Comment: It would be best beneficial to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far to avoid the community doing any heavy lifting.